# Rails ajax keeps trying to render a template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Rails .js.erb ajax to trigger a controller action without rendering a template, a very simple task.

But no matter what I try, Rails tries to render a template every time

At the moment my code looks like this

```
  <%= form_tag change_index_superadmin_shops_path, remote: true do %>
    <select id = "live_select" name = "table[live]">
      <option value="false">All</option>
      <option value="true">Live</option>
    </select>
  <% end %>
```

and in my routes

```
namespace :superadmin do
  resources :shops do
    collection do
      post :change_index
      get :index_recurring_credit
    end
  end
end
```

and my controller

```
  def change_index
    @shops = Shop.where(live: true)
  end
```

So why am I getting a "Template is missing" error even though I declared `remote: true` on my form? And how do I fix this.

PS i do have a change_index.js.erb file

Comment: Post your `change_index.js.erb` file. I think its the culprit.

Comment: @Pavan all it contains is a console.log statement for debugging

Comment: That's it? I believe it contains more.

Comment: No. All that will go into that file is a jquery `.html()` call to replace a table. The problem is that `change_index.js.erb` isn't running at all and Rails is trying to redirect

Comment: Okay.Can you post it? I want to have a look at it.